# angular add label to checkboxes created with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I am using angular 5

I am using the following code to create multiple checkboxes, and need to give them labels

```
<input type="checkbox" *ngFor = "let v of options[0].options" [value]="1" [name] = "1">
```

When using HTML I would use

How can I use label within the *ngFor and create the suitable labels?

Thanks

Comment: Needed options data pls post that in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<label *ngFor = "let v of options[0].options">
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

or you can use `ng-container`

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let v of options[0].options">
    <label for...></label>
    <input ...>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution.

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor = "let v of options[0].options">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"  [value]="v.value">{{v.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```